# Errors in rendering a RSS page

Tags: xml, rss

I'm trying to render a RSS page for a site.
The RSS it'self works fine and it's also validated. It's built by a PHP script I made.

However, when I implement the CSS and the XSL, and I call the page, what I get is this message:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 4 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

This document was created as the result of an XSL transformation. The line and column numbers given are from the transformed result.
```

But the line 4 is not empty at all, nor the rest of the document.

Please, here there is the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/feed">
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="xsl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-size:0.83em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="channel/link" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="channel/title" />
            </xsl:element>
        </div>
        <div class="Snippet" style="border-width:0; background-color:#FFF; margin:1em">
            <div class="titleWithLine">
                <xsl:value-of select="channel/description" />
            </div>
            <dl style="padding-right:1em">
                <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
                    <dd>
                        <xsl:element name="a">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </dd>
                    <dt>
                        <xsl:value-of select="description" /><br />
                        <span class="comments"><xsl:value-of select="pubDate" /></span>
                    </dt>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <xsl:value-of select="channel/copyright" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The page is "visible" here:

http://www.melanie-music.net/feed/?feed=rss2

you will get the error above but if you go to check the Source, you find the code

What can I do please?

---

**EDIT:**

deleting the XSL line and adding the argument

```
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
```

to the RSS tag, at least I made fworking the CSS
Still all the CDATA not correctly interpreted

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anybody has what I got, the way to remove the attribute to the `<rss>` tag is good choice

For the CDATA, I foudn this topic:
[Styling RSS feed using XSLT issues with CDATA tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912179/styling-rss-feed-using-xslt-issues-with-cdata-tags)

which is great, but you need to work a bit with it, in order to make it working in an acceptable way and having added

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
```

to have the HTML5 (let's say)